# C# - How can I access the value using properties of classes in an override method?

Tags: c#

My Code:

```
public class A
{

    public virtual void displayDetailInfo()
    {
    }

}
```

---

```
public class B : A
{

    public String _a;
    public int _n;

    public B() { }
    public B(String _a, int _n)
    {

        this._a = _a;
        this._n = _n;
    }

    public String A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { this._a = value; }
    }
    public int N
    {
        get { return _n; }
        set { this._n = value; }
    }

    public override void displayDetailInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A);//To obtain value entered in Main(i.e. f.A)
        Console.WriteLine(N);//To obtain value entered in Main(i.e. f.N)
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        A v = new A();
        A v1 = new B();
        B f = new B();                            
            f.A = Console.ReadLine();  //Value to be accessed          
            f.N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Value to be accessed 
            v1.displayDetailInfo();
    }
}
```

How can I get the value(f.A and f.N) I entered in Main accessed from the overrided method in class B(i.e. displayDetailInfo()). The code I wrote doesn't obtains any value(i.e. Console.WriteLine(A) gives no value of f.A). So how can I get the value of f.A and f.N from overrided displayDetailInfo()?

Comment: You can't, because the instance of `B` you're referring to from `v1` is an entirely different instance from the instance of `B` where yo're modifying `A` and `N`. Why are you creating two instances, if you don't want two independent sets of state?

Comment: Try calling `f.displayDetailInfo();` and check if you see those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use `new` to create a new object, you are creating a new, independent object that has its own state.

Here, you are creating 3 separate objects - `v`, `v1`, `f`.

```
A v = new Vehicle();
A v1 = new B();
B f = new B();
```

Changing a property of one of these objects does not affect the properties of the other two objects whatsoever.

Here you change the properties of `f`, but the properties of `v1` is not affected.

```
f.A = Console.ReadLine();          
f.N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

This is why when you call `v1.displayDetailInfo()`, it prints null and 0. null and 0 are the default values of `string` and `int` respectively. `v1`'s properties have not been set yet, so they hold the default values.

To fix this, just call `f.displayDetailInfo()` instead.

Comment: Thank you sir, f.displayDetailInfo() just worked out fine.

Comment: @Deshant If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because you `v1` is a different instance of `B` than the one you want to get the values from (`f`)

Calling `f.displayDetailInfo()` should give you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

You are setting A of a different object than what you are calling displayDetailInfo on.
I think you meant to do this:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    A v = new Vehicle();
    B v1 = new B();                       
    v1.A = Console.ReadLine();  //Value to be accessed          
    v1.N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Value to be accessed 
    v1.displayDetailInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for `v1` to have data you entered in `f`. The class is just a blueprint, `v1` and `f` are different instances that exist in different parts of the heap.

`v1.A` is not the same as `f.A` and `v1.N` is not the same as `f.N`

To see the values you entered, you better call:

`f.displayDetailInfo()`

Also, you're using properties wrong. If you want to use backing fields, the ones with the underscores (`_n` and `_a`), you better make them private. And unless you want to have additional logic to the getters or setters you are better off not using backing fields altogether and use auto implemented properties:

`public string A { get; set; }`

`public string N { get; set; }`

Comment: I think you meant  "better off using auto implemented properties".

Comment: @juharr Oops. No I actually meant, not using backing fields, but yeah, same thing. Nice catch :)

Comment: @dimlucas Thank you sir, your suggestion worked out. Thank you for your explaination:)